# Circles in canvas not revolving properly in proper circle

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm making a simple program using canvas where I have a sun, and there are three planets rotating around it. I managed to make the Sun and the planets. However, when I try to revolve the planets around the Sun, for some reason the planets do not revolve in a perfect circle.

Here's my code:

```js
const canv = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canv.getContext('2d');

canv.width = window.innerWidth;
canv.height = window.innerHeight;

// Get the DPR and size of the canvas
var dpr = window.devicePixelRatio;
var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
// Set the "actual" size of the canvas
canvas.width = rect.width * dpr;
canvas.height = rect.height * dpr;
// Scale the context to ensure correct drawing operations
ctx.scale(dpr, dpr);
// Set the "drawn" size of the canvas
canvas.style.width = `${rect.width}px`;
canvas.style.height = `${rect.height}px`;



var w = canvas.width;
var h = canvas.height;

var circle = function(color, r) {
    ctx.fillStyle = color;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(0, 0, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    ctx.closePath();

    ctx.fill();
}

const earth = new Image();
  earth.src = 'earth.png';

mwidth= canvas.width/2;
mheight= canvas.height/2;

var i = 0;
function draw() {
  ctx.save();

    // paint bg
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

    // set origin to center
    ctx.translate(w / 2, h / 2);

    // draw sun
    circle('yellow', 20);

    // rotate + move along x
    ctx.rotate(i / 100);
    ctx.translate(100, 0);

    // draw planet
    circle('green', 10);

    // rotate + move along x
    ctx.rotate(i / 100);
    ctx.translate(150, 0);

    // draw planet
    circle('blue', 15);

    // rotate + move along x
    ctx.rotate(i / 100);
    ctx.translate(180, 0);

    // draw planet
    circle('red', 10);

    ctx.restore();

    i++;
window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
//setInterval(draw, 1);
```

```css
body {margin: 0; padding: 0}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Our Universe</title>
</head>
<body> 
<canvas id='canvas'>Sorry, your browser does not support this feature.</canvas>
</body>  
</html>
```

You can see if you run the above snippet that the planets are revolving in a strange manner (they are not revolving in perfect circles.). Can someone explain why and help me correct this?

Comment: What's your reasoning behind `ctx.rotate(i / 100);` ? if you replace all those instances with `ctx.rotate(360);`  (except the one following directly behind the yellow circle)you get perfect circles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want them to be perfect circles, there's nothing like trigonometry. :-)

To find the point on a circle, you use:

```
x = radius * cosine(angle);
y = radius * sine(angle);
```

...which gives you a value that is `-radius` to `radius` for each. You offset those by the center of the circle.

So for your example, you could use your game counter (`i`) multiplied by some speed variable and calculate the center point of each of the three orbiting planets, like this:

```js
const canv = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canv.getContext("2d");

canv.width = window.innerWidth;
canv.height = window.innerHeight;

// Get the DPR and size of the canvas
let dpr = window.devicePixelRatio;
let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
// Set the "actual" size of the canvas
canvas.width = rect.width * dpr;
canvas.height = rect.height * dpr;
// Scale the context to ensure correct drawing operations
ctx.scale(dpr, dpr);
// Set the "drawn" size of the canvas
canvas.style.width = `${rect.width}px`;
canvas.style.height = `${rect.height}px`;

let w = canvas.width;
let h = canvas.height;

let mwidth = w / 2;
let mheight = h / 2;

let circle = function (x, y, color, r) {
    ctx.fillStyle = color;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    ctx.closePath();

    ctx.fill();
};

/* Not currently used
const earth = new Image();
earth.src = "earth.png";
*/

const circles = [
    {color: "green", radius: w / 8, size: 10, speed: 0.02, },
    {color: "red",   radius: w / 6, size: 15, speed: 0.012, },
    {color: "blue",  radius: w / 4, size: 10, speed: 0.01, },
];

let i = 0;
function draw() {
    ctx.save();

    // paint bg
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

    // Draw sun
    circle(mwidth, mheight, "yellow", 20);

    // Draw circles
    for (const { speed, radius, color, size } of circles) {
        const angle = (i * speed) % 360;
        const x = radius * Math.cos(angle);
        const y = radius * Math.sin(angle);
        circle(mwidth + x, mheight + y, color, size);
    }

    ctx.restore();

    i++;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

```css
body {margin: 0; padding: 0}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Our Universe</title>
</head>
<body> 
<canvas id='canvas'>Sorry, your browser does not support this feature.</canvas>
</body>  
</html>
```

I haven't used `transform` in that, there didn't seem to be any need, but I'm relatively new to canvas programming so you might want to adjust the above to use that instead of explicit `x`/`y` coordinates.

---

Side note: I'm not sure the scaling code in there is correct, the canvas looks slightly distorted to me. But that wasn't the question. :-)

Comment: Thanks for this great implementation! Your code is much more easier to use than mine and works awesome!

Answer (score 2):

From my perspective, the planets are rotating with respect to the last one. It's because you rotate and translate the whole `ctx` after each planet is added. (See how the last example works [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/rotate)) It would work perfectly if you want to show how moons will orbit for instance.

A better implementation is by setting the trigonometric position of each planet.

```js
const canv = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canv.getContext('2d');

canv.width = window.innerWidth;
canv.height = window.innerHeight;

// Get the DPR and size of the canvas
var dpr = window.devicePixelRatio;
var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
// Set the "actual" size of the canvas
canvas.width = rect.width * dpr;
canvas.height = rect.height * dpr;
// Scale the context to ensure correct drawing operations
ctx.scale(dpr, dpr);
// Set the "drawn" size of the canvas
canvas.style.width = `${rect.width}px`;
canvas.style.height = `${rect.height}px`;



var w = canvas.width;
var h = canvas.height;

var circle = function(color, r, orbit, velocity, time) {
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    x = Math.sin(-time * velocity / 100) * orbit
    y = Math.cos(-time * velocity / 100) * orbit
    ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}

const earth = new Image();
  earth.src = 'earth.png';

mwidth= canvas.width/2;
mheight= canvas.height/2;

var i = 0;
function draw() {
    i++;
    ctx.save();
    // paint bg
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    // set origin to center
    ctx.translate(w / 2, h / 2);
    // draw planets
    circle('yellow', 20, 0, 0, i);
    circle('green', 10, 50, 3, i);
    circle('blue', 15, 120, 2, i);
    circle('red', 10, 170, 4, i);
    ctx.restore();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
//setInterval(draw, 1);
```

```css
body {margin: 0; padding: 0}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Our Universe</title>
</head>
<body> 
<canvas id='canvas'>Sorry, your browser does not support this feature.</canvas>
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This certainly helped me understand why my code had this bug.